# My app keeps stopping in Android Emulator with mpw error which I think is related to server connectivity

Tags: android, android-studio

The logs, in this case, are very weird. I am not able to figure out the issues that are causing the connectivity errors with the servers. Please help me out with this mpw 29503 error:

```
09-06 17:08:37.756 2285-4073/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetRec: [239] abno.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: mpw: 29503: 
    at alfn.b(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):4)
    at alfn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):28)
    at abno.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):1)
    at abno.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):7)
    at abnl.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):2)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):15)
    at nmb.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):1)
    at bdb.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):1)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):11)
    at nmc.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):8)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):7)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):2)
 Caused by: mpw: 29503: 
    at mvf.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):3)
    at aejp.b(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):4)
    at aema.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):4)
    at nof.a(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):6)
    at noj.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):44)
    at axja.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):2)
    at nsg.run(:com.google.android.gms@12521024@12.5.21 (040700-189987672):27)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at nya.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so wired, because of task invocation on `ThreadExecutor`. To get correct log of your issues, you should wrap action, which you submit in background with your tools (executor Service, Rx, or even AsyncTask) with `try-cath` block.